# Counting Theory: How many strings of length...?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm having hard time understanding the question.

So the question is: 
Consider all strings whose letters belong to the set A= {a,b,c,d,e}

a)How many strings of length 6 are there that begin with a vowel and end with a vowel?

So what I don't understand is, there are 5 given letters yet it says how many strings of length 6? 
My try is that 2*5*5*5*5*2. Not sure if right. Can someone help?

Comment: Because it wants strings from the set, it allows repeats. So your guess is spot on.

Comment: Thanks for your help! What happens if we want to have at least one "a"?

Comment: @user3015986 Try counting the strings where "a" doesn't appear at all, and then subtract this number from the total number of possible strings.